# ugettext and ugettext_lazy functions not recognized by makemessages in Python Django

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I'm working with Django 1.5.1 and I'm experiencing some "strange behaviour" with translations. I'm using `ugettext` and `ugettext_lazy` in the same Python file. If I organize the imports as:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as trans
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

or

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as trans, ugettext_lazy as _
```

The strings marked as `trans("string")` are skipped when running `makemessages` command.

However, if I don't rename the `ugettext` it works well with both versions:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

or

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _
```

Now `trans("string")` works well.

**So, does anybody know why this import renaming is causing the renamed function not to be called?** Is this an actual Python "limitation" I didn't know when renaming more than one function inside the same module?

---

**UPDATE**

After some testing, I've realized that even creating an empty python module inside an app with the following code it doesn't work:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as translate

a = translate("string")
```

However, if using `_` for the alias it works:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

a = _("string")
```

My **conclusion** is: *You can only use the `_` alias for `ugettext` and `ugettext_lazy` (or any other related translation function) in Django or else it won't be recognized by `makemessages` command*.  The technical explanation can be found in Robert Lujo's answer.

Thanks!

Comment: You can "rename" as many symbols (function or whatever) as you want, Python names are just aliases, and both import forms (one liner or two-liners) are equivalent, so the problem is elsewhere. FWIW I strongly suspect you rebind the name "trans" to something else somewhere after the import...

Comment: Hi! I'm not overriding `trans` in the module (I did a search with Eclipse). Could it be possible because of '_' renaming?

Comment: `_` is a valid Python name and has no magical power. wrt/ renaming, `from x import y as z` is the exact equivalent of `from x import y; z = y; del y` so here again nothing magical happens. wrt/ your assertion that "you're not overriding `trans`", a simple text search might not be enough. A very common (anti)pattern is star import override, ie `from x import y; from z import *`, where it happens that `z` also exports a `y` symbol. Also and if you're not familiar with Python, Python's function _don't_ live in an isolated namespace, they are ordinary variables.

Comment: I don't know if there could be a name collision with any Django variable called trans or translate. I'm running out of ideas. I don't use wild imports in Python to avoid problems.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've just updated my question after further testing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Django command utility makemessages internally calls [xgettext](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html) program like this:

```
cmd = (
    'xgettext -d %s -L Python %s %s --keyword=gettext_noop '
    '--keyword=gettext_lazy --keyword=ngettext_lazy:1,2 '
    '--keyword=ugettext_noop --keyword=ugettext_lazy '
    '--keyword=ungettext_lazy:1,2 --keyword=pgettext:1c,2 '
    '--keyword=npgettext:1c,2,3 --keyword=pgettext_lazy:1c,2 '
    '--keyword=npgettext_lazy:1c,2,3 --from-code UTF-8 '
    '--add-comments=Translators -o - "%s"' %
    (domain, wrap, location, work_file))
```

(source can be found [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py#L98)). So, some keywords are predefined by the [xgettext](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html) utility (check reference for --keyword):

- for python - gettext, ugettext, dgettext, ngettext, ungettext, dngettext,  _

and some are added by django utility:

- gettext_lazy , ngettext_lazy , ugettext_noop , ugettext_lazy , ungettext_lazy , pgettext , npgettext , pgettext_lazy , npgettext_lazy

Keyword **trans** is not in any of these keyword sets, so you should not use it for marking texts for translations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've just updated my question after further testing.

Comment: This was exactly the problem! I was renaming the `ugettext` and `ugettext_lazy` functions using an alias that isn't included as a keyword and therefore it was skipped. It isn't a matter of imports. So, to conclude, just say that the ONLY alias allowed is `_`. Thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 9):

Unexpected ugettext aliases can be handled by overriding the `makemessages` command, such as in:

```
from django.core.management.commands import makemessages

class Command(makemessages.Command):
    """
    Extends the makemessages command to look for additional aliases.
    """
    xgettext_options = makemessages.Command.xgettext_options + ['--keyword=_lazy']
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#customizing-the-makemessages-command

Answer (score 0):

These notes about [multi-language support for Django project](http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/14/multi-language-support-in-a-django-project/) may let you identify what is wrong. Most probably renaming is not the root cause for failure.

Some warnings in these notes:

- Each template for your web site must load the i18n tag library using the `{% load %}`
- You need to create the locale directory manually before running makemessages - that you normally did, if not you get an error message
- Language files must be compiled to `.mo` files before you use them - that you did also

EDIT

In the page i linked to my post, they are using this syntax in templates:

```
{% trans "Hello" %}
```

is it something you tried already ?

Comment: The problem isn't related with this, as using ugettext_lazy as _ works perfectly and using ugettext without alias too.

Comment: I've just accepted @RobertLujo's answer as he perfectly answers my question. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way for resolving no .po files generation are the development server.

During my development server is running I executed the command **makemessage**. Command output was right, but my .po files were updated :

```
(venv_crypto_bot) macbook-pro:django_project dauzon$ python manage.py makemessages -a 
processing locale fr
processing locale en
processing locale ru
```

**Stop the development server and re-run the command resolves my issue.**

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `compilemessages` command, to call the original `compilemessages` command with extra arguments.

For example, to support `from django.utils.translation import pgettext_lazy as _p`:

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/4/20
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management.commands import makemessages


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Make messages in en_US and zh_CN, support _p, ignore venv folder."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        text = "-l en_US -l zh_CN --ignore ?env -v3"
        command = makemessages.Command()
        getattr(command, "xgettext_options").append("--keyword=_p:1c,2")
        call_command(command, *text.split())
```

Notes:

`_p:1c,2` represents `_p('msgctxt', 'msgid')`, function with two arguments like `pgettext_lazy`