# Is there a good shortcut convention for ugettext_noop in python/django?

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

When doing i18n support for django apps it sometimes comes up to have to use [`ugettext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.ugettext) and [`ugettext_noop`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.ugettext_noop) in the same file. It's a common convention to import `ugettext` as `_` which is a nice convention in code. I'm wondering if there is such a convention for `ugettext_noop`? Maybe `__`?

I'm envisioning something like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _, ugettext_noop as ?

MY_CONSTANT = ?('translate me later')

def my_function():
    return _('translate me now')
```

Fill in the `?`.

Comment: Import it like it is without convention: `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_noop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the answer answer [ugettext and ugettext_lazy functions not recognized by makemessages in Python Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509160/ugettext-and-ugettext-lazy-functions-not-recognized-by-makemessages-in-python-dj/16510454#16510454) the short answer is:

- you could alias ugettext_noop to something else, but [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html) won't recognize if alias is not one of the gettext keyword aliases.

Summary: only one short alias (`_`) can be used, for other gettext functions you should not use aliases.