# Django uggetext as __ instead of _ breaks makemessages

Tags: django, django-i18n

I just came across a weird bug (?) where I initially had

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

Which I changed for

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as __
```

But, surprisingly, running `./manage.py makemessages --all` after doing that breaks all translations, they basically get all commented in my `.po` files, as if they weren't recognized as being translations anymore.

Going back to `_` and running `makemessages` fixes it. I don't quite follow why the name of the variable matters, and I wonder how I should name my ugettext and ugettext_lazy when I need both, for consistency.

*Django 1.8, with python 2.7.14*

Comment: I hope the answer below solved your issue...!

Comment: Indeed, I somehow missed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the internals of the [`gettext`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/) utility and more specifically of the [`xgettext`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html#xgettext-Invocation) command.

In short, in order to mark strings as translatable you must *wrap* them in specific keywords (i.e `translate("hello world")`, `translate` here is the keyword). The `xgettext` program works for many programming languages. Each language has its own [predefined keywords](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html#xgettext-Invocation) (press `Ctrl + f` and search for `--keyword`).

In Python, these keywords are (note the `_` at the end):

> For Python: `gettext`, `ugettext`, `dgettext:2`, `ngettext:1,2`, `ungettext:1,2`, `dngettext:2,3`, `_`

`xgettext` command has several options which alter it's behavior. One of these, is `--keyword` option. When you invoke the `xgettext` command with the `--keyword` option, then all strings in a python file will be considered translatable if they are wrapped in one of the predefined keywords or the `--keyword` option(s) you gave. If, for example you run `xgettext --keyword=jimmy_hendrix` then all strings like `jimmy_hendrix("hello world")` will be included in your `.po` file.

But, you will never run this command, in Django, explicitly. You use the `makemessages` command. Looking at the [source of `makemessages` command](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py#L561), you can see that Django provides additional `--keyword`s for marking strings for translation. In fact, these keywords are the same as Django's additional functions for translation.

After all these, I think it's clear now that aliasing `__` or `___` will not work since it's not in the list of Django's `xgettext` command invocation, neither in the predefined keywords of `xgettext` command.

You may look at an outdated, [but still valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509160/ugettext-and-ugettext-lazy-functions-not-recognized-by-makemessages-in-python-dj).

Also, an example of [`xgettext` on MDN, using PHP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/gettext).

Comment: Is this somehow configurable through django, or should we rather stick with what's at our disposal? I read the other answer and it's not clear if I can just add my own shortcuts/alias on top of the basic ones, or if that's considered as a bad practice.

Comment: I'm afraid that you cannot alter this behavior since it is written in the core and any attempt to override it, IMO it would be considered as a hack. That said, if anyone has another opinion to this, I would be glad to update this answer!